# ReactJS componentwillreceiveprops does not produces correct value

Tags: reactjs

My sidebar component is

```
render() {
 return (
  <Link to={"/test/1"} >Task 1 </Link>
  <Link to={"/test/2"} >Task 2 </Link>
  <Link to={"/test/3"} >Task 3 </Link>
  <Link to={"/test/4"} >Task 4 </Link>
 )
}
```

And my details component is

```
componentWillReceiveProps(){
    console.log('id: '+this.props.params.id)
    axios.get(this.state.url+'post/'+this.props.params.id)
        .then(response => {
           console.log('id again: '+this.props.params.id)
         }      

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error ' + error);
        });
}
```

Both components are visible in the same page and my initial URL is `localhost:3000/test/1`
And my console gives `id: 1` and `id again: 1`. When i click on **Task 2** in my sidebar my console gives `id: 1` and `id again: 2`, and my network gives the api call of `post/1`.

Breifly the issue is on each clicks of my sidebar, before calling the api the value is its previous value and after api call it gives the correct value of the link clicked. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `componentWillReceiveProps` is called when there is any prop changes. But component's props are not changed before calling `componentWillReceiveProps`. Which means `this.props` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` points to the current props instead of upcoming props. (i.e. `id: 1` log in your case)

When react call `componentWillReceiveProps`, it passes the upcoming props as the parameter. So you can access the upcoming props in `componentWillReceiveProps` like this

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log('id: '+nextProps.params.id)
    axios.get(this.state.url+'post/'+nextProps.params.id)
        .then(response => {
           console.log('id again: '+nextProps.params.id)
         }      

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error ' + error);
        });
}
```